# canceling a function calling another function

Tags: jquery

Many functions I want execute only if some image has the class - `imgact`.

```
some function(){    
    if (!$('.imglib').hasClass('imgact')) {return;}
```

To avoid repeating the above line I created a function:

```
function ifno(){
    if (!$('.imglib').hasClass('imgact')) {return;}
}
```

and then:

```
some function(){
    ifno();
...
```

doesn't work. `some function` is executed.

How to do this?

Comment: It's because the `return` statement is in `ifno()`, not `somefunction()`. Return a boolean from `ifno()` instead, then put that in an `if()` statement in `somefunction()` - *however* you now have two `if` statements for the same logic. If `ifno()` is reused in other places, that's fine, but I'd suggest you consider your pattern here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing return statement from your `ifno` function, you can do something like this.

```js
$(".imglib").click(function(){
  if(ifno(this)){
  alert('have class');
  }
  else{
    alert('do not have class');
  }
})

function ifno(element){
  return $(element).hasClass('imgact');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="imglib">test</button>
<button class="imglib imgact">test1</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return the result of your function instead, and then evaluate that in your code. This will allow you to check for a true or false and continue as otherwise.

So your check class function should be as follows.

```
 function ifno(){
        return $('.imglib').hasClass('imgact');
    }
```

And then your code to check for the class and run the function otherwise in your example :

```
someFunction(){

if(ifno()){
//do whatever
    }

else{
 // exit function.
    }

}
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Great advice, I've amended this and will further explain my answer.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Brilliant, that's very helpful advice as a coder. Sometimes I prefer it for readability, but you're right, it does just make everything tighter and more efficient. Thanks for taking the time to explain this and make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to return something from function like below function will return false

```
function ifno(){
    if (!$('.imglib').hasClass('imgact')) {return false;}else{return true;}
}
```

OR

```
function ifno(){
       retun $('.imglib').hasClass('imgact');
}
```

and then

```
some function(){
    if(ifno()){
     console.log('Has Class');
    }else{
     console.log('Not Has Class');
    }
...
```

I have Edited my answer after missing `if-statement` which noticed @RoryMcCrossan, Thank You

Comment: You're not doing anything with the value you return from `ifno()`

Comment: Given your update, why not just `return $('.imglib').hasClass('imgact');`?